# What's the best way to position a column next to the page content?

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

Here what I have so far,
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXRYXY

What is the best way to position the green boxes (they represent advertisements) to the right side of the page content? In the code below I tried doing it with width:50%.

Should I plan out the width of my content and the width of the advertisements before even writing any code? I'm confused by how people plan out the creation of their webpage, because my screen width is 1920px and if I use that width as a model than users with smaller screens will view my webpage differently. What dimensions should I use when planning the measurements and positioning of my elements?

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">
 <div id="head">
  <div id="header" style="float:left;">
    <p id="title">
      <a href="#">Blog Title</a>
    </p>
    <p id="description">Blog Description</p>
  </div>

  <div id="navbar" style="float:right;">
    <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
      <li><a href="#">Start Here</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Section 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Section 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Section 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="welcome-wrap" style="clear:both;">
  <div id="first-time">
    <h2>First time here?</h2>
    <p style="margin:0;">Fusce ut finibus purus, quis convallis orci. Donec a est eget tellus euismod tincidunt non eu urna. Sed id gravida dui. Phasellus sed faucibus nisl. Proin blandit nisl eu lectus convallis.</p>
    <br>
    <br> If it's your first time here,
    <a href="#">read this</a>
  </div>

  <div id="topics">
    <h2>TOPICS</h2>
    <p><a href="#"><strong>Link Topic 1</strong></a>
      <p><a href="#"><strong>Link Topic 2</strong></a>
        <p><a href="#"><strong>Link Topic 3</strong></a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="inner" style="clear:both;">
  <div id="content">
    <div class="post">
      <a href="#"><img width="300" height="200" src="contentimg.jpg"></a>
      <p>Mauris gravida diam id sem blandit, vitae vestibulum nunc interdum. Nulla congue felis eget tincidunt rhoncus. Nunc rutrum, massa a venenatis fermentum, nisi leo dictum sapien, ut venenatis quam neque sit amet quam. Nunc efficitur hendrerit
        hendrerit. Sed sit amet tortor ex. Pellentesque dapibus porttitor massa eu iaculis. Curabitur varius vulputate sagittis. Aenean ac mauris eu justo lobortis accumsan a vitae est. Praesent imperdiet quam vitae porta lacinia.</p>
      <a class="more-link" href="#" rel="nofollow">Continue Reading</a>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

    <div class="post">
      <a href="#"><img width="300" height="200" src="contentimg.jpg"></a>
      <p>Nulla porttitor rhoncus justo in molestie. Aliquam sed vehicula mauris, quis egestas augue. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec congue arcu mollis aliquet aliquam. Pellentesque purus dolor, commodo eget tincidunt nec, fringilla quis magna.
        Nam suscipit cursus purus, in sodales tortor egestas suscipit. Proin ut augue sit amet nulla laoreet maximus id eu nibh. Pellentesque dapibus finibus egestas.</p>
      <a class="more-link" href="#" rel="nofollow">Continue Reading</a>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

    <div class="post">
      <a href="#"><img width="300" height="200" src="contentimg.jpg"></a>
      <p>Fusce ut finibus purus, quis convallis orci. Donec a est eget tellus euismod tincidunt non eu urna. Sed id gravida dui. Phasellus sed faucibus nisl. Proin blandit nisl eu lectus convallis, vel ultricies risus varius. Morbi id nibh enim. Suspendisse
        potenti. Nulla facilisi. Quisque congue lacinia dapibus.</p>
      <a class="more-link" href="#" rel="nofollow">Continue Reading</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="sidebar" style="float:right;">
    <div>
      <p>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS1uD8Fj5M9sS4Lo1OrKIycgx2gMDnEE7zHru3j--pDFlwqujXiKA"></a>
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS1uD8Fj5M9sS4Lo1OrKIycgx2gMDnEE7zHru3j--pDFlwqujXiKA"></a>
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS1uD8Fj5M9sS4Lo1OrKIycgx2gMDnEE7zHru3j--pDFlwqujXiKA"></a>
      </p>
      <p>
        <a href="#"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS1uD8Fj5M9sS4Lo1OrKIycgx2gMDnEE7zHru3j--pDFlwqujXiKAg"></a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
    body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#wrap{
    margin-left:500px;
    margin-right:500px;
    max-height:5000px;
}

/*head*/

#head{
    min-height:135px;
    width:960px;
    margin-top:50px;
}

#title a{
    font-size:2em;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
}

#description{
    font-size:0.9em;
}

#header p{
    margin:0 !important;
}

#navbar ul li{
    float:left;
    padding-left:1.5em;
    margin-left:0;
}

#navbar ul li a{
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:1.2em;
    margin-left;0;
}

/*sub head*/
#welcome-wrap{
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
}

#first-time{
    float:left;
    width:450px;
    padding-right:150px;
}

#topics{
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:green;
    width:300px;
    height:280px;
}
/*content*/

#inner{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
}

#sidebar{
    float:right;
    width:50%;
}

.post a{
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after putting your code in an IDE(Notepad++) I have figured out your problem.

First off you have to close off your main div #wrap.

Second off the property value margin-right: which was given to #wrap is completely unnecessary due to the fact that it is not serving any visual purpose and also preventing your (advertisements) from being floated to the right side of your page.

and if you want to move the sidebar up or down just add to their margin-top or margin-bottom respectively.

Comment: no problem Calisto :)